# Cannot install iptables-service

Tags: iptables, service, repository, fedora-22, dnf

I cannot install iptable-service on fedora 22. When i type the command

> dnf install iptables-service

, it throws the error mentioned below.

Error: Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'updates' (and some more info).

I tried manually entering the repo link in the browser and it asked me to save meta data file , so i know the repo works.

What might be the problem? how do i solve this? i cannot install anything it throws this error. Atleast is there any alternative method to install iptables-service?

Thank you.

Edit below is the full error i get:-

```
Error: Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'updates' from 'https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=updates-released-f22&arch=i386': Cannot prepare internal mirrorlist: Curl error (60): Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates for https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=updates-released-f22&arch=i386 [Peer's Certificate issuer is not recognized.]
```

Comment: The package is `iptables-services` (note plural).  But it looks like you have a bigger problem with `dnf`; we will need to see all the error output to have a chance of helping.  Please edit it into your question.

Comment: @MadHatter hi thanks for the response, i have added the full error.

Comment: What other changes have been made to the system?